# CouchDB cannot find ports on SQL Server 2012

Tags: couchdb, nosql

We are attempting to migrate our CouchDB from an old server to a new with and upgrading from 2008 R2 to 2012. As such we have decided to reinstall the CouchDB.

While doing this we cannot get the socket server to start from what appears to be a port issue. When we attempt to open the ports manually we cannot seem to find success. Is there any suggestions as to how to get the CouchDB running either using new open ports or opening the current ports?

Or could this be another issue all together?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** - just **2012** - corrected.

Comment: Are you using Couchbase or CouchDB? They are two separate products.